# Display jQuery POST result as HTML page

Tags: jquery, moodle

Moodle's Glossary search consists of a POST form that results in a full HTML page on success.

How can I (programmatically) submit a POST request and have the response loaded as the current tab's content with proper history handling?

I've looked around a bit and found the possibility of just `window.write()`ing the data, but I've been told that method is a bit evil and should be avoided if possible.
I also wouldn't imagine it to play nicely with the browser history.

My code so far:

```
$.post("/mod/glossary/view.php", {"id": 12, "hook": "apple"}, data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: You mean opening results in a separate tab or in a same page show post `results` ?

Comment: Maybe something like? `$("body").html(data)`  Maybe with a `history.pushState` for "proper history handling"

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I want to make it so you can click on the glossary term in the little modal window and get redirected to the search result page of the glossary module with the term already in the search bar and all matching entries below.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to replace the whole page with the result data that is sent back?

If the data is being returned OK, you could do this:

```
$.post("/mod/glossary/view.php", {"id": 12, "hook": "apple"}, data => $('body').html(data))
```